# enabling sticky keys under xorg (awesome desktop manager)

Tags: linux, xorg, awesome-wm

I would like to enable "sticky modifier keys" under archlinux + awesome, and I haven't found the correct info.

Comment: What is "sticky keys"?

Comment: right, I meant "sticky modifier keys", it means that pressing a modifier key acts as a toggle and usually the toggle is released on the next key press, so keys don't have to be pressed simultaneously but can be pressed in sequence. This is an accesibility for disabled users feature on OS-X, Gnome and probably Windows, and I find it more confortable and less hand straining with the feature on.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I've got it. There is a utility called xbkeys for setting accessibiltiy options for xorg.

From xkbset manual ($ xkbset man):

```
To switch sticky keys on or off, and optionally set or reset:
() two keys pressed at the same time stops sticky keys;
() a modifier pressed twice will be locked:

    [-]{sticky|st} [[-]twokey|[-]latchlock]...
```

I ran this:

```
$ xkbset sticky -twokey -latchlock
```

That command can go in .xinitrc

```
# turn on stickykeys. don't let two keys pressed at the same time disable it.
# don't turn on "latch lock", ie pressing a modifier key twice "locks" it on.
xkbset accessx sticky -twokey -latchlock

# don't expire these settings. (run xkbset q exp for details.)
xkbset exp 1 =accessx =sticky =twokey =latchlock
```

Comment: Here is a link to `xkbset`: http://www.math.missouri.edu/~stephen/software/#xkbset

Comment: This is available in debian in the package `xkbset`.

Comment: This answer is very helpful!  Now I just want to find a way to limit the sticky behavior to the Shift keys.

Comment: @JesseHallett Did you find a way to limit the sticky behaviour?

Comment: @JayeshBhoot Yes; xkb has "latch" variants of some keys. I get sticky shift by mapping my shift keys to `ISO_Level2_Latch` which acts like shift for modifier purposes. (Some programs that look for the shift keycode specifically don't work with `ISO_Level2`, especially games.) I have my config online; but you'll need to look up some documentation on the specific details of applying custom key mappings. https://github.com/hallettj/dot-xmonad/blob/master/home/.config/X11/xkb/symbols/hallettj

Comment: @JesseHallett thank you for the pointer! I will try this out asap.

Comment: There's a lovely bug in GNOME lately where booting up with X leaves sticky keys off even though the accessibility menu shows them as remembered on (I think this doesn't happen with Wayland, but Wayland has a profoundly brain-damaged implementation of sticky keys which is approximately unusable unless you're literally only ever hitting one modifier key at a time, as opposed to using sticky keys to have that option along with multi-pressing and any/all of the other benefits of latch-to-lock modifiers) - I think `xkbset sticky -twokey latchlock` is the thing that finally lets me fix it.

Answer (score 6):

You can use Xmodmap to set a key lock for the Scroll, Kana, Num, Caps, and Shift keys. Also some ISO groupings keys can be remapped this way. For example, on my keyboard, to set Left Shift as a toggle, use this:

xmodmap -e "keycode 50 = Shift_Lock"

use "xev" to get the correct keycode.

Just add the command inside the quotes to a file named .Xmodmap and restart X to have the changes permanent.

Unfortunately, I don't think there is a keycode to Lock the Control, Alt, or Meta keys. If you post a more specific question and add a decent bounty, I may be able to work out a shell script and/or xorg change to make this possible.

Comment: Unfortunatelly I haven't got any more points to offer, I really am missing sticky modifiers as in cntrl, window, alt, meta...

Comment: XKB is a better way to do this. Check [Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/X_KeyBoard_extension)

Answer (score 2):

One way to enable sticky keys is to press the `StickyKeys_Enable` key.  If you don’t have it mapped to your keyboard you can simulate the keypress with e.g. Xdotool:

```
> xdotool key StickyKeys_Enable
```

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know, Xorg doesn't support this. It's not inconceivable for a custom keyboard driver to implement this, but I have never come across such a thing.

Comment: Mmm... I would really like to have this without having to resort to Gnome or XFCE... bummer!